# Automatically marking all endpoints as exception in ArcGIS topology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, line, topology

I have inherited a dataset of lines representing roads, which were inconsistently connected. I have applied the *Must Not Have Dangles* rule to fix the topology, but the visualized errors also include endpoints. In my situation, endpoints *are not* errors.

I know I can mark each endpoint as an exception using the *Error Inspector*, but I have over 5,000 points which are as such. *Is there a way I can mark them systematically, so to focus on the undershoot/overshoot inconsistencies?*

A Python approach would also do for me.

Comment: How is your topology set up?  If I understand your question, you need to change your rules and remove any 'Endpoint Must Be Covered By' rules.

Comment: You've probably seen this in the documentation for dangles - "It may also be used in cases where lines typically connect to other lines, as with streets. In this case, exceptions can be used where the rule is occasionally violated, as with cul-de-sac or dead-end street segments."  From that it sounds like you cannot automate the exceptions.  A workaround would be to get the endpoint errors, select the features in error, query them out, rerun topology rules without the offending features.

Comment: @jbalk I like this approach, but I am very disappointed ESRI hasn't apparently thought about this. After all there are countless situations in the real world where the dataset is large. How would you go about implementing what you said? I haven't been able to find a way to deal with exceptions other than *manually* address them one by one. And with over 5,000 points this is not going to work.

Comment: Yes I agree, but not surprised.  There is a long list of this nonsense from ESRI.  I haven't used topology rules too much so I probably can't help you.  I'm pretty sure you can use the error features to select underlying features.  Assign an attribute to those features, set def query to remove them, rerun topology check.

Comment: Check out also this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341936/how-to-find-errors-gaps-and-overlaps-in-a-line-feature-class-in-arcmap/341938?noredirect=1#comment558780_341938

Comment: Check out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341936/how-to-find-errors-gaps-and-overlaps-in-a-line-feature-class-in-arcmap/341938?noredirect=1#comment558780_341938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, but I solved it to some extent using the tool **Feature Vertices to Points**. You can specify the point type as DANGLE option, so you get only the free extremes of the lines, with all the their attributes and (the most useful) the dangle length. Then you can filter the points by selecting by attributes or location.