# How to find errors (gaps and overlaps) in a line feature class in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, topology

I have a line feature class that contains roads that were manually edited. Now I want to check if all road crossings have been edited correctly. I want to check that there is no small gap or overlap (<1m) at the road crossings. Dead ends are not errors.
Which tool in arcmap could I use to highlight these errors?

To find small overlaps a solution is here, using first TOPOLOGY and second the tool "Feature Vertices to Points": [Automatically marking all endpoints as exception in ArcGIS topology?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225108/automatically-marking-all-endpoints-as-exception-in-arcgis-topology)

I am still looking for a soution for small gaps.

[image: Small (<1m) gap and overlap in line feature class]

Comment: What license level do you have?  Are you interested only in identifying them or fixing them, and if the latter one by one or by batch?  If you have Advanced I would run a planarize with an acceptable tolerance to fix gaps and extends.  If you have Advanced or Standard you could also run one or more of the editing tools (snap, extend, trim) in batch.  If you have Basic the Integrate tool could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternative approach :

1) create end points on all lines

2) create buffers of a given size around all points.

3) use spatial join to count the number of lines that are intersected by the buffer: if you have more than one line, this is either a gap or a dangle (and you can screen out the dangles)

Comment: Thank you, this solution works perfect to adjust a line feature class in a supervized way. (One problem: if the overlap is very small eg. 0.0058 meters, ArcMap does not recognize it as a dangle, which must be a bug. With the Integrate tool as @johns proposed very small gaps and overlaps in the line feature class can be corrected automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be familiar with TOPOLOGY. There are several rules like overlaid, pseudonodes...etc that arcmap finds errors automatically.
Check some tutorial if you will find hard from esri resources.

[Topology in Arcgis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/topologies/topology-in-arcgis.htm)

1- **Must not have pseudonodes** (Fixed by topology)
This will catch the issue if you may have any break line on the middle of segment (not at intersection)

2- **Must not intersect** and **Must not self-intersect** (Fixed by topology)
This will catch all errors in intersection. Like your first error where , if they have break line, you can
 catch this issue sorting the feature class by the length of the line.

3- **Must Not have dangles** (Fixed by topology)
This will catch the start and the end of a line if the dont touch any line. So if you are supposed to check a city, majority of these point will be on the corners, a quick check it is not as bad as you say. 
This issue can be combined with solution given below by **radouxju**, than you can check just some particular cases. Or if you have license of autocad map, export the file in DWG and the topology of autocad has snap/osnap errors detection.

Comment: I checked topology using the rule "Must Not Have Dangles". The problem there is, that end points are marked as dangles as well.

Comment: Extended the answer, hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

1) create the end points of all lines using "feature vertices to points"

2) use "integrate" ON A COPY of your lines with a given tolerance

3) create the end points of all lines of the "integrated" feature class

4) run spatial join on between the two sets of points. All points that moved were within the tolerance value to another line or vertex. There might be a few displacements linked with other vertices on the same line (especially if your tolerance is large), but I assume that you use a small tolerance, so those should be rare. Screen out the dangle points and only the gaps will remain.